# I Want to Compare two XML Files Using Python and Print Common attribute Values and Uncommon attribute Values in both the files

Tags: python, excel, xml, read.csv

As Iam New to Python I need some help to compare two XML files.
These are the Following Conditions:

1. To print Common fullPath Name and Name (fullPath and Name are the attributes present in the XML file)  between the two XML files.
2. To print the values which is present in only first file and not in second file.
3. To print the values which is present in only second file and not in first file.

Later, Have to print this output in excel file having different sheets.
for example (1st condition in sheet 1, 2nd condition in sheet2, 3rd condition in sheer3 of the same excel file.)

Can please anyone help me with the code that satisfies the above condition which I have mentioned.

This is the code which I have tried.

```
from lxml import etree


Base = etree.parse('Base.xml')
Target = etree.parse('Target.xml')

Base_fullPath = Base.xpath("//Member/@fullPath")
Target_fullPath = Target.xpath("//Member/@fullPath")
Base_name = Base.xpath("//Member/@name")
Target_name = Target.xpath("//Member/@name")

def match(Base_fullPath, Target_fullPath, Base_name,Target_name):
    Base_fullPath_set = set(Base_fullPath)
    Target_fullPath_set = set(Target_fullPath)
    Base_name_set = set(Base_name)
    Target_name_set = set(Target_name)
    if (Base_fullPath_set & Target_fullPath_set,  Base_name_set & Target_name_set):
       x = open('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Common_FullPath.csv', 'w')
       y=(Base_fullPath_set & Target_fullPath_set)
       z=(Base_name_set & Target_name_set)
       print("common details Full Path: \n", *y, sep='\n', file = x)
       print("\n")
       x = open('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Common_name.csv', 'w')
       print("\n common details Name: \n", *z, sep='\n', file=x)
    else:
        print("No Matches Found")
match(Base_fullPath, Target_fullPath, Base_name,Target_name)


def non_match_elements(list_base, list_target):
    non_match_base = []
    non_match_target = []
    for i in list_base:
        if i not in list_target:
            non_match_base.append(i)
    for i in list_target:
        if i not in list_base:
            non_match_target.append(i)
    return non_match_base
    return non_match_target

list_base = Base.xpath("//Member/@*")
list_target = Target.xpath("//Member/@*")

non_match_base = non_match_elements(list_base, list_target)
x = open('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Present_in_base.csv', 'w')
print("\n Base Details: \n", *non_match_base, sep='\n', file = x)
non_match_target = non_match_elements(list_target, list_base)
x = open('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Present_in_target.csv', 'w')
print("\n Target Details: \n", *non_match_target, sep='\n', file = x)

import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Common_FullPath.csv')
df1 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Common_name.csv')
df2 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Present_in_base.csv', delimiter=';;', on_bad_lines = 'skip', engine = 'python' )
df3 = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\Present_in_target.csv', delimiter=';', on_bad_lines = 'skip', engine = 'python')

with pd.ExcelWriter("C:\\Users\\pvl\\Desktop\\New folder\\combined.xlsx") as writer:

    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Common_name", index=False)
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="base_Details", index=False)
    df3.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = "target_Details", index=Fal
```